# Connect four, check for winners in C

Tags: c

```
if ((board[y][x] == 'o' && board[y][x + 1] == 'o' && board[y][x + 2] == 'o' && board[y][x + 3] == 'o')  
||  (board[y][x] == 'o' && board[y][x - 1] == 'o' && board[y][x - 2] == 'o' && board[y][x - 3] == 'o') )
    {
     printf("you win!\n");
    }
```

this is what i tried to do with char *board[10][10]
anyway simple way to solve this? I have tried many other methods like for() loop and doWhile() loop, but nothing seems to work. please advice, thanks

Comment: Any error displayed ? (What do you mean by nothing seems to work)Could you give the whole code ? (`x` and `y` = ?) What you have here is quite simple and could be correct, a few additional checks might be needed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I can see here is that you're only checking in a single direction, so if the last counter is dropped into the middle of a '4' then this won't accept it as a win.

I would probably have a function that goes through each direction in turn (think compass points), counts the length of the unbroken 'line' in each direction, and stores it in a temporary variable. After this has been done for each direction, add together the lines in the opposite sides, and see if it adds to 4.

There's probably a million other ways to do this though!

Answer (score 0):

I think for-loop is OK for your problem. For position (x,y), (x,y)+(1,0)*k(k=0,1,2,...) will do the same thing as your first line do.

Actually, I think you should check for 4 directions, not just x-axis.

Like I just said, (-1,0) and (1,0) will help you to check positions around (x,y) in x-axis.

Similarly, for other directions.